# fixed div on header should not refresh on submit

Tags: html, form-submit

I create a fixed Div on the top.

**css**

```
#header {
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
height: 20px;
width: 100%;
background: green;
}
```

I want, when I submit the page , the fixed div on the header should not refresh.

Comment: Header div should remain on the same state, when I submit the page

Comment: So, you are trying to submit to the same page, but doesn't want to refresh the whole page? Explain the purpose please...

Comment: @ATOzTOA I want to submit on the second page not same page, but I want the header should not refresh, means one header for all pages that's state remain the same

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to load part of the HTML page then AJAX is solution.

Comment: Without using ajax, on submit.

Comment: I don't think it is possible if you are expecting a response from the server. If you just want to display a message, may be there might be a way to do it. Let me know the end to end flow in brief. It might shed some light (Abstract page structure, what u r expecting to do on submit and the result after submit).

Answer (score 1):

Use frames if you want part of the page to remain same (like the website logo) and the main content navigable.

Comment: frames and frameset tags are not supported in HTML5. Is it a good idea to still use them?

Comment: iframes are still supported in HTML5.